# MySQL Warning: IP address could not be resolved

Tags: php, mysql

I just noticed this warning in the MySQL Workbench log:

**[Warning], IP address '112.30.xxx.xxx' could not be resolved: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.**

What does it mean?  I have the MySQL port firewalled so that any incoming TCP traffic is blocked.  Any ideas where this is coming from?  How to I eliminate the warning?

Comment: your DNS failed to resolve the IP, thats all it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as rtfm said it means your DNS failed to resolve the IP, And means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

Please also reference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/393862/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: Thanks. Since we use only IP resolution it makes sense to disable it.

Comment: Your Welcome, Cheers!

Comment: Important.  If you do add skip_name_resolve to the ini file, make sure that none of your users are using "localhost" since only IP addresses can be used, you might be locked out.  Use 127.0.0.1@whatever for your user account.  I discovered this the hard way since it is not very clear in the documentation.

Comment: Not correct, Mike G.  The MySQL documentation (for v5.5, v5.6, v5.7, and v8) clearly states that, when enabling the `skip_name_resolve` option,  the "host column values in the grant tables must be IP addresses or localhost."  Thus, it is perfectly safe to enable this option and continue to connect to MySQL via `localhost`.